# TikZ: Use \enquote in text along a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, csquotes

I'd like to place some text along a path in TikZ. Said text is a quote, and for quotes I invariably reach for the `csquotes` package. However, `\enquote` does not appear to work when used with text along paths.

Consider the following FMWE (fairly minimal working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,-1) {\enquote{Howdy}};
\path[decorate, decoration={text along path, text={\enquote{Text along an arc}}}] (0, 0) arc[start angle=270, end angle=360, radius=3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Attempting to compile this causes `xelatex`, `pdflatex` or whatever other compile I use to hang indefinitely. Removing the `\enquote` in the path decoration makes everything work. The included node shows that `csquotes` is not in principle incompatible with TikZ.

So, my questions are:

1. why doesn't `\enquote` work here?
2. how can I *make* it work?
3. if I can't make it work, is there another way of getting typographically correct quotation marks without having to manually choose them?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I've since found it's not *only* `\enquote` that's causing trouble but also such things as `\dots`. My first two questions, at the very least, remain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decoration splits the `text` argment up in tokens and places them individually, i.e. `\enquote` and then `Text along an arc`. [See the explanation in the manual.](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.text)
You can't use `\enquote` here just as much as you wouldn't be able to use `\textbf` for example.

Luckily, the `csquotes` package provides some user-macros discussed in section §11.6 of [its manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/csquotes/0), amongst others these are `\textooquote` (*o*pening/*o*uter) and `\textcoquote` (*c*losing/*o*uter).
With these, the text at least will use the auto style provide by the facilities of the `csquotes` package.

These, you will have to enclose in `{}` as well.

Without `csquotes` you would have to manually enter the literal quotation marks of your language.
In that case, they would need to be enclosed in `{}` as well unless you were using LuaLaTeX.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,-1) {\enquote{Howdy}};
\path[
  decorate,
  decoration={
    name=text along path,
    text={\textooquote}Text along an arc{\textcoquote}
  }
] (0, 0) arc[start angle=270, end angle=360, radius=3];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: +1 I couldn't get my answer using `\textooquote` etc. to work because I didn't realize they need to the braced.